# files being returned with find which do not match the pattern specified

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

My intention is to show the directories and files (with a .dat or .DAT file extension only in a tree structure only. The following examples of my code in my bash script is returning these but also files with .txt / .xmlfd extensions.  Can anyone point out what is wrong with my code please?

```
sudo -${user} sh -c 'cd '${userdirectory}'; find . -type f | grep -i '*.dat' | sort -u | xargs tree -L 3 -C'
```

```
sudo -${user} sh -c 'cd '${userdirectory}'; find . -type f -iname '*.dat' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u | xargs tree -L 3 -C'
```

```
sudo -${user} sh -c 'cd '${userdirectory}'; find . -type f -name '*.[dD][aA][tT]' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u | xargs tree -L 3 -C'
```

Comment: can try this `sudo -u ${user} sh -c 'cd '${userdirectory}'; find . -type f -iname "*.dat" -o -iname "*.DAT" | sort -u | xargs tree -L 3 -C'`

Comment: Even the syntax highlighting here shows you that single quotes don't nest.

Comment: Thanks @Ashok. Unfortunately this seems to ignore the output being in the tree format :(

Comment: Thanks choroba. Only noticed the syntax highlighting when I looked at the responses my question had generated :)

Answer (score 2):

Your grep regex does not make much sense: An asterisk at the start of a regex has the meaning of a literal asterisk, and would only match if one of the filenames produced by `find` contains an asterisk. The period matches any character, hence your `grep` basically searches for substrings such as `*xdat` or `*%dat` in the filename. If you search for files where the name ends in `.dat` , grep for `[.]dat$`:

```
grep -i '[.]dat$'
```

The `[.]` matches a literal dot, and the `$` anchors the match at the end of the line.

Alternatively, you can let `find` do the selection, by either specifying a glob pattern,

```
find .... -iname '*.dat'
```

or if you *do* want to use a regexp, by

```
find .... -iregex '[.]dat$'
```

Of course all this requires that your filenames don't contain a newline character.

In any case, make sure that the quoting is correct: If the whole string is wrapped between single quotes, you need to escape the single quotes for your *find* or *grep* command.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone point out what is wrong with my code please?

`tree` expects *directories*, so your basic premise is broken.
You can't call it on a specific list of *file* arguments that way, but Looks like all you really need is `-P` to have it do that selection itself.

```
$:  tree --version # in case anyone needs to know
tree v1.6.0 (c) 1996 - 2011 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Kyosuke Tokoro

$: tree -L 3 -C -P '*.[dD][aA][tT]' # or '*.dat|*.DAT'
.
├── a.DAT
├── a.dat
├── b.DAT
├── b.dat
└── foo
    ├── a.DAT
    ├── a.dat
    ├── b.DAT
    ├── b.dat
    └── bar
        ├── a.DAT
        ├── a.dat
        ├── b.DAT
        ├── b.dat
        └── baz
```

(The `-L 3` is working:)

```
$: printf "%s\n" foo/bar/baz/*
foo/bar/baz/a.dat
foo/bar/baz/a.DAT
foo/bar/baz/b.dat
foo/bar/baz/b.DAT
```

To elaborate on the question you actually asked, let's look at some of the specific problems you had.

```
sudo -${user} sh -c 'cd '${userdirectory}'; find . -type f | grep -i '*.dat' | sort -u | xargs tree -L 3 -C'
```

1. I think you mean `sudo -u $user`.
2. Fix your quoting.
3. Fix your regex (or other means of file limitation).
4. `tree` expects directories, see above.

Addressing each -

`sudo -${user}` is going to pass the username as a stack of options, some of which may or may not require arguments and break syntactically - you should hope they do. What you wanted is

```
sudo -u "${user}" ...
```

Most quotes do not nest. Best practice is to quote variables unless you have a good, specific reason not to, so take advantage of switching between single and double when you can.

Remember that single quotes prevent variable interpolation, so if your variable exists in your current environment, you need to have the shell insert it when the line is parsed, *before* the resulting command is sent to the `sudo`.

Be aware that if one set of quotes is inside another, the outher generally define the interpolation and *internal* quoting rules:

```
$: foo='bar baz'; echo "foo='$foo'"; echo 'foo="$foo"'; echo "foo=\"$foo\" "
foo='bar baz'
foo="$foo"
foo="bar baz"
```

Accordingly,

```
sudo -u "${user}" sh -c "cd '${userdirectory}'; : do stuff;"
```

This will pass the single quotes to protect any embedded spaces in `${userdirectory}`, but will still insert the *value* of `${userdirectory}` as **before** passing the whole thing to `sudo`.

Note that as written, if the `cd` fails, it will execute any remaining commands wherever it was. Generally, it's good practice to check that if possible. e.g.,

```
sudo -u "${user}" sh -c "if cd '${userdirectory}'; then : do stuff; else echo aborting; fi"
```

The `find` as given will return all plain files under the current directory. As user1934428 pointed out, `-iname` will let you return case-insensitive matches, eliminating the need for a separate `grep`.

```
sudo -u "${user}" sh -c "if cd "${userdirectory}"; then find . -type f -iname '*.dat'; fi" # watch those quotes
```

As an aside, `grep` uses regex, not globs. Your `grep -i '*.dat'` should have been `grep -i '\.dat$'` - though again, as user1934428 pointed out, don't use `grep` when doing this sort of thing, even if you preferred regex to globbing; you'd still eliminate the extra process much the same way, but with `-iregex '[.]dat$'` instead of `-iname '*.dat'`, as in

```
sudo -u "${user}" sh -c "if cd "${userdirectory}"; then find . -type f -iregex '[.]dat$'; fi"
```

Passing either through a simple lexical `sort` is also probably not going to do what you wanted, but but that's really another discussion widely available if you search.

As we mentioned above though, `find` isn't what you need at all, so `xargs` also becomes superfluous (and never mind `-exec`). If you *were* doing something that it worked for, c.f. [BashFAQ #20](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for good examples and explanations.

...but you don't need `find` *or* `xargs.   Just call` tree`with the`-P` pattern(s).

```
sudo -u "${user}" sh -c "if cd '${userdirectory}'; then tree -Cv -L 3 -P '*.[dD][aA][tT]' --prune --dirsfirst; else echo Failed cd, aborting; fi"
```

Be aware `tree` is *globbing*, so it *isn't* a real regex, but it also may not have all the same toys available that the shell does. For example, setting `shopt -s nocaseglob` doesn't appear to work, as it probably isn't replicated into `tree`'s subshell.

That means to match both upper and lower cases you could use `-P '*.dat|*.DAT'`, but that would not match a file named `foo.Dat`, while -P '*.[dD][aA][tT]' will. Select accordingly.

`-v` should help for sorting. Play with `--prune` and `--dirsfirst` to get the output where you want it, such as eliminating directories in your output that don't have any valid hits.